# How best to convert types between database and web service call?

Tags: c#, datetime, odbc

I am developing an ASP.Net C# web application that should access the database using ODBC then pass the gotten data to a web service.

I face a problem in converting date as I tried using Convert.ToDateTime and parseDate to change the format of the dates acccessed from the database and change it to the suitable formate needed for the web service.
for example:

```
the database datetime storage format is "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
07/15/2011 03:05:10 pm
the webservice datetime storage format is "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
15/07/2011 15:00:00
```

How I can change and convert these different formats for datetime data types so that the web service accepts it properly?

Also, there is a boolean data type in the web service which is stored as integer in the database, how I can handle that so that the web service accepts the boolean data type in a correct way?

for example:

```
the isGiven variable may have the value of 0 in database while it should be false or true in the web service as it accepts it as boolean only.
is there an implicit conversion between int and bool data types?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the database datetime storage format is "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"

No, it's not. The database doesn't store the datetime value as a formatted string, it stores it numerically representing a point in time. When you read it you get it as a `DateTime` value, not a `string`.

To convert the DateTime value to the format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` you just use a custom format string:

```
theDate.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss")
```

Converting an integer to a boolean can either be done when you read it from the database:

```
cast(isGiven as bit)
```

or afterwards:

```
reader["isGiven"] != 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I discovered that my computer system date and time format should bein the same format as the web service and my conversion functions were working fine but the System converts it again to another format when I call Convert.toDateTime() when passing the parameter to the web service. Anyhow, thanks for your useful answer that shows a way to convert to date/time formats in C#.

Comment: @user493325: When converting from a string to DateTime it will accept different formats, but you may run into problems with dates that can match more than one format, e.g. `08/01/2011` can be either January or August. Calling `Convert.ToDateTime` doesn't convert to a date format, it converts to a DateTime value. That value is then converted back to a string somewhere as the web service sends data as text, so you might have to provide a date format or a `CultureInfo` object to the code that does that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I may be over-simplifying, but couldn't your web service method just accept a bool and put the mapping logic inside the service call (or a helper method) before you write to the database?

```
public void DoSomething(bool myBool)
{
    var myBoolConverted = myBool ? 1 : 0;

    myDatabase.DoSomething(myBoolConverted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    string s = "07/15/2011 03:05:10 pm";
    // get database date / time
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));

    // format as web service date / time
    string ws = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```